# What is this green mark on my minimize button?

Tags: windows-10

I am using Windows 10 and the applications pictured are File Explorer (top left) and an in-progress installation of CUDA 11.4 (bottom right). The green dot appears on whichever window is currently in focus.

The green mark appears on File Explorer windows, and Blender's windows, but not on Chrome or Edge windows. It also doesn't appear on either of my other two computers that I can see.

- **Startup programs**: With everything turned off, it still shows up.
- **Nvidia Quadro**: I can't find any evidence that it's on this machine.
- **Nvidia Control Panel**: The green mark appears on this window, too. All the settings look the same as they ever have. I can't find anything that seems relevant. Without more information, I'd just be guessing at random.

Literally, as I was typing this edit, I went to check the Start menu and see if it had any kind of new mark on it, and discovered "Recently Installed: Nsight..." Three Nvidia applications that seem to be for remote GPU monitoring? Development? Administration? Looked through all their settings and can't find anything relevant, but it might be related to something else that got installed recently.

These marks recently started showing up on my windows. This is exceedingly difficult to Google, because the algorithm is convinced I'm trying to figure out how to minimize a window... and won't show me any other results.

It could be a new feature from a recent Windows update, but I can't figure out which one or what it does for me. It doesn't do anything when I click on it (except minimize the window), and it doesn't have a tooltip. I don't see any unexpected applications running, either.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you enabled QUADRO VIEW? Pretty sure this is a "Feature" of either QUADRO VIEW or nVidia Control Panel. You could try and find the feature, or do a clean install of the latest drivers for your GPU, and only install the components you require (core GPU driver and CUDA stuff, and uncheck the "tools")

Comment: I'm not familiar with QUADRO VIEW. Nvidia says that it's standard on Quadro drivers, or as a standalone application. I'm not using a Quadro device, and I haven't downloaded that app. Could that have been included in a CUDA SDK?

Comment: I'm not with that machine, so I'll have to check the settings later.

Comment: "Could that have been included in a CUDA SDK?" Possibly, I would focus my search on nVidia Control Panel and any other nVidia utilities the driver update has installed

Comment: "It must be a new feature from a recent Windows update" - It has nothing to do with an update to Windows.  Does it appear on every window, if it does, does it appear while in Safe Mode?  You can [edit] your question to provide this vital information

Comment: 1) Disable your startup items. Reboot.  Does it go away?  Add them back one at a time and watch for re-occurrence.  2) [Disable 3rd party shell extensions](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) (this is certainly not MS making an ugly green thingy). Reboot. Does it go away?  Add them back one at a time.  You can also use the Process Explorer to see what DLLs are loaded into the explorer; however; this could be done in process for the explorer or externally via user mode application.

Comment: Updated with some new information